# Magento Admin Keeps on Redirecting to Login Page

Tags: magento

I have a Magento 1.9.2.1 installation that I have not updated and not logged into since a long time. When I try to log in today any menu item I select from the admin dashboard redirects me back to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that the hosting disk space quota was reached and Magento was unable to write state information to disk. I increased the quota and the admin portal is fully functional once more.